# I delete "expo-notification" and use "@react-native-firebase/messaging" and I get two messages

Tags: react-native, expo

I got a push message when I was in the background using "expo-notification".

It was convenient, but I tried to use a different method, so I did "npm uninstalled".

I also deleted the contents of "app.json" and deleted all the related sources.

Afterwards, I receive push messages using "@react-native-firebase/messaging", and when it is in the background, I receive messages in the form I received in the existing "expo-notification".

There are two push messages in the background.

I don't understand at all. I deleted all the relevant sources, but why is it being received in the old way as well?

```
expo: 49.0.11

in "app.json"
    remove line "googleServiceFile" "./google-services.json"

copy /android/app/google-services.json 
    build.gradle - classpath 'com.google.gms:gogole-services:4.3.3'
    build.gradle - apply plugin 'com.gogole.gms.google-services'

npx expo prebuild --clean
npx expo run:android --device
```